# Breeze/Entity Framework: only one collection returns when objects added to multiple collections?

Tags: entity-framework, breeze

I'm not sure if this is a Breeze problem or EF problem, but tables in EF look fine to me.

I have a `TradingAccount` which tracks all transactions and holdings. The holding also contains a collection of related transactions. So, one transaction may be added into two collections.

Here are my related classes:

```
public class TradingAccount
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Transaction> Transactions { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Holding> Holdings { get; set; }
}

public class Transaction
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int AccountId { get; set; }
    public Account Account { get; set; }
}

public class Holding
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int AccountId { get; set; }
    public Account Account { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Transaction> Transactions { get; set; }
}
```

Here is query for breeze:

```
Context.TradingAccounts.Include("Transactions")
                       .Include("Holdings")
                       .Include("Holdings.Transactions")
                       .Where(t => t.Id == id);
```

The problem is that when I added a transaction to both TradingAccount.Transactions and Holding.Transactions, only Holding.Transactions return value, TradingAccount.Transactions don't.

Is there something I did wrong?

Comment: To identify where is the problem, monitorize the OData requests and responses. To do so, you can use Fiddler or, depending on the browser, hit F12, and look if your browser lets you monitor the request and responses (for example in Chrome there is a 'network' pane).

Comment: Something doesn't quite connect here. I'm actually expecting Holding.Transactions to not return anything since I don't see `Transaction` having `HoldingId` foreign key and `Holding` navigation property. Also what is the relationship between Account and TradingAccount?